# Secure contact form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contact-form

Currently I am working on a contact form(E-mail contact form) for somebodies website.

After some research, I heard that there were ways of securing you're contact form and that got me thinking.

1.Is there an actual big threat if you don't "secure" you're contact form other then spams ? What would be the worse possible scenario ?

2.If I were to follow some guidelines on how to make a contact form that is secure, where would be the best place to start ? (Plugins, tutorials any recommendations would help !)

Thanks guys !

Comment: https://luxsci.com/blog/secure-web-pages-and-web-forms-what-you-need-to-know.html some answers to your question after googling secure html form

Comment: It is not a REAL QUESTION as stackoverflowers say it. Do a research and try some code and if you are stuck in code somewhere post your problem with code you already tried and then you will get an answer thanks. for a quick start click here --> https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enDE602DE602&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=secure%20contact%20form

Comment: Well for starters, the 'security' of your form depends upon what you're doing with the data (SQL injection, etc.)

Comment: The question itself is a bit broad, but it's a good thing to be thinking about.  Unfortunately "secure" isn't easily provable.  And there are a lot of factors that can go into it.  As you develop this, you can certainly post code on the Code Review Stack Exchange site to ask for feedback, and where you have specific questions regarding specific implementations we'd be happy to help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My bad if my question wasn't legit. Im pretty new to Stackoverflow. And thanks for the comments guys, I'll look into what you guys gave me !

Comment: @Chunmuchy: It's not a *bad* question, and it's certainly an important one for a developer to ask.  (Better to validate security than to assume it.)  It's just not entirely within the defined scope of Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @David: I gotcha ! I think I was defiantly pointed out last time, not asking a question that was relevant to stack overflow last time too, Ill keep that in mind.

Comment: Aspects: 1. Preventing automated abuse. [CAPTCHA] 2. Preventing general abuse. [Never let your user set the 'From' address ever, or the 'To' address if you can help it] 3. Preventing email injection. [sanitize your inputs] The best general-case solution is to *not* have a contact form at all. Just post the email address.

Comment: @Sammitch: yeah I think from what I could find out, just posting the email address seems like the easiest solution to my trouble right now. It seems like with my coding level, actually making a contact form seems out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Security" is an extremely broad topic, but for starters you can secure the data being transferred by buying  a (--or generating your own self-signed) SSL certificate. That will encrypt any data sent to your form. Whether or not you need the encryption depends on what kind of info you're asking for. If you're just asking for suggestions you probably don't need it to be too secure, but if you're requesting sensitive info like CC numbers or SSNs it's actually illegal not to have SSL (at least here in the states).

- http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQsKdtjwtYI
- http://franz.com/support/tutorials/ssl-tutorial.htm
- http://google.com

Comment: Buying a SSL certificate is defiantly something that is new to me, Ill have to look into that. But, for the meantime, the person that I am making a website for is a landscape architect and her website is generally for a portfolio and not for huge businesses. That said, would it be safe to assume that I wouldn't need a SSL cerfiticate?

Comment: @Chunmuchy: You can always create a certificate, it's just up to the user whether or not to trust it.  The need would come from the nature of the data being provided.  Does any of the data provided by the site need to be kept away from snooping parties?  Does any of the data provided by the *user* need to be?  If the user ever supplies a password, yes.  Or any personal or identifying information.  Even supplying an email address can be argued as a need for encryption, at least for a subset of users.  Balance that subset with the need for the information as a business decision, I guess.

Comment: @Chunmuchy My guess is no, you  most likely don't need a secure form, but again, it depends on what kind of info you're asking for. Use your best judgement. General rule is: If you're asking for info that could be used to steal someone's identity then use SSL.

Comment: @Chunmuchy but rest assured that if you /do/ decide to use SSL, it's extremely easy. Your host provider can set up the whole thing for you and it doesn't require any changes to the actual PHP code.

Comment: @David: From what you said, I now defiantly feel the need of a more secure option. Knowing my client, it seems there will be situations where sensitive information might be given back and fourth. So as of now, I think I will remedy the situation by simple posting an email address on the contact page.

Comment: So far I am getting some great information from you guys (David, Adelphia) and I will defiantly looking to SSL's. But in the mean time I think I will just take a safe route of just posting a E-mail address in text form on the website. 

While I'm at it, would this email me button be the equivalent of just having an email address posted on a contact page? 

[link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/mailbutton.shtml)

Comment: If the visitor is typing their message into a form on your wesite then yes. Another alternative is to just use a link with the email address in it like this `<a href="mailto: myemail@gmail.com">Email me</a>` ..this will open the user's email client so they can send an email.

Comment: if using `mailto:` then no, you don't need an SSL because the message isn't being sent through your server.

Comment: @Adelphia: Alright ! thanks man ! That helps me out a lot, I'll defiantly look into the "mailto" option, seems like the best alternative to just posting an email address.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is there an actual big threat if you don't "secure" you're contact form

You need to treat all user input as a potential threat. It's your responsibility to mitigate potential threats according to your exposure.

The severity of a threat can't be generalized: you need to look at the value of your assets, the visibility of the application, and the type of attacker you may encounter (automated/passive or targeted/active).

> 2.If I were to follow some guidelines on how to make a contact form that is secure, where would be the best place to start ? (Plugins, tutorials any recommendations would help !)

Many application frameworks come with some form security features but you are still responsible for understanding the mechanics. There is no such things as a turn-key security: context is everything.

Security is a deep topic but here are some guidelines:

- **never trust user supplied data**
- prefer **whitelisting** to blacklisting; if you can't whitelist than you really have to understand output escaping
- in fact either way you **really** need to understand output escaping: understanding data in context and escaping output appropriately is essential
- understand the http protocol and understand how php abstracts it

Here some good jumping off points:

- http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet
- https://github.com/padraic/phpsecurity
- https://leanpub.com/securingphp-coreconcepts
- https://leanpub.com/buildingsecurephpapps

Comment: Hey thanks for the information man ! Think I can say that this was a pretty successful post that I made so far. All the answers everyone gave opened up a pretty new direction on what I should study next. Cheers.